# Como forçar arquivos do tipo .txt a ser feito download

Tags: php, sistema-de-arquivos

Tenho uma página, mas não quero que quando clique em arquivos do tipo .txt faça download, ao invés de exibi-los. Estou desenvolvendo essa página em PHP.

Vi alguns script na WEB, porém ele está forçando o download de arquivos do tipo .txt sem que ele seja ao menos clicado.

Segue o código que estou fazendo:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9"/>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
    <title>FTP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
    <body>
        <?php
        if(isset($_GET['path']))
            $dir =  $_GET['path'];
        else
            $dir = '..'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'ftp';
        foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dir) as $file) {
            if (!$file->isDot()) {
                if ($file->isDir()) {
                    echo '<div class="pastas">';
                        echo '<a href="index.php?path='.$dir. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$file.'"><img src="icones/archive.ico" width="30px" height="30px"/></a>' . $file->getBaseName();
                    echo '</div>';
                } else {
                    switch($file->getExtension()) {
                        case 'txt':
                        echo '<a href=""><img src="icones/text.ico" width="30px" height="30px" /></a>'.$file->getBaseName();
                        break;
                        case 'jpg':
                        echo '<a href=""><img src="icones/jpg.ico" width="30px" height="30px" /></a>'.$file->getBaseName();
                        break;
                        case 'gif':
                        echo '<a href=""><img src="icones/jpg.ico" width="30px" height="30px" /></a>'.$file->getBaseName();
                        break;
                        case 'docx':
                        echo '<a href=""><img src="icones/doc.ico" width="30px" height="30px" /></a>'.$file->getBaseName();
                        break;
                        case 'doc':
                        echo '<a href=""><img src="icones/doc.ico" width="30px" height="30px" /></a>'.$file->getBaseName();
                        break;
                        case 'pdf':
                        echo '<a href=""><img src="icones/pdf.ico" width="30px" height="30px" /></a>'.$file->getBaseName();
                        break;
                        case 'ppt':
                        echo '<a href=""><img src="icones/ppt.ico" width="30px" height="30px" /></a>'.$file->getBaseName();
                        break;
                        case 'rar':
                        echo '<a href=""><img src="icones/rar.ico" width="30px" height="30px" /></a>'.$file->getBaseName();
                        break;
                        case 'zip':
                        echo '<a href=""><img src="icones/zip.ico" width="30px" height="30px" /></a>'.$file->getBaseName();
                        break;
                        case 'avi':
                        echo '<a href=""><img src="avi.ico" width="30px" height="30px" /></a>'.$file->getBaseName();
                        break;
                        case 'mp3':
                        echo '<a href=""><img src="icones/mp3.ico" width="30px" height="30px" /></a>'.$file->getBaseName();
                        break;
                        case 'wmv':
                        echo '<a href=""><img src="icones/wmv.ico" width="30px" height="30px" /></a>'.$file->getBaseName();
                        break;
                        case 'exe':
                        echo '<a href=""><img src="icones/exe.ico" width="30px" height="30px" /></a>'.$file->getBaseName();
                        break;
                        default:
                        echo '<a href=""><img src="icones/default.ico" width="30px" height="30px" /></a>'.$file->getBaseName();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
?>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Segundo [esta postagem](http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/forum/topic/force-a-file-to-download-instead-of-showing-up-in-the-browser) , é possível fazer isso alterando o arquivo `.htaccess` com o seguinte:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:txt)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Isso faz com que todos os arquivos de texto sejam servidos com os headers:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment;
```

Segundo essa [resposta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10085431/195417), para usar o recurso de definir o header pelo htaccess, é necessário ativar um modulo do Apache.

Answer (score 12):

Para força um download de arquivos txt eu utilizaria a `function` logo abaixo:

**Código:**

```
function download($arquivo){
      header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
      header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream;");
      header("Content-Length:".filesize($arquivo));
      header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$arquivo);
      header("Pragma: no-cache");
      header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
      header("Expires: 0");
      readfile($arquivo);
      flush();
}
```

**Utilização do Código:**

```
download('forca_download.txt');
```

**Referências:**

- [PHP](http://www.php.net)
- [PHP - function header](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

**Obs:** *Seria uma forma de não configurar nada no servidor de forma transparente, e que funcione em todos os servidores, que em muitas vezes não deixa alterar as configurações.*