# Trabalhando com string php

Tags: php

Tenho um projeto para emissão do arquivo de remessa de boletos para bancos e cooperativas de crédito. Na montagem do arquivo defino uma variável e monto as linhas como no exemplo abaixo:

```
$conteudo .= '085';                                                        
$conteudo .= '0000';                                                       
$conteudo .= '0';
```

Gostaria de saber se é possível, no final, gerar essas informações em formato de arquivo e forçar o download sem criar o arquivo fisicamente no servidor.

Comment: Sim é possível! seria mais ou menos como nessa [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13843/91)

Comment: Para complementar a pergunta é melhor que você clique em editar, em vez de criar uma resposta. Com relação ao problema das duas quebras de linhas. Verifique se não há quebras de linha antes de abrir a tag do php <?php. Ou se você estiver incluído outros arquivos. Verifique se nestes arquivos não há quebra de linha também após fechar a tag ?>. Além disso, não é recomendável utilizar a tag de fechamento, caso você não vá incluir conteúdo estático(HTML) depois.

Answer (score 4):

Sim, isso aqui deve resolver:

```
$fileName = "remessa.txt"; //colocar aqui o nome do arquivo



header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream;");
header("Content-Length:".strlen($conteudo));
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileName);
die($conteudo);
```

Comment: Verdade. Tinha esquecido desse detalhe.