# Download arquivos e imagens

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Estou usando o codigo `window.open(url, '_blank');` em javascript para fazer download de arquivos, ele baixa todos os tipo automaticamente, mas imagens ele abre a imagem  numa pagina e não baixa.

Comment: Acho que esse link pode lhe ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13826/como-for%C3%A7ar-arquivos-do-tipo-txt-a-ser-feito-download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem uma opção sem precisar usar JS.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Basta usar o atributo HTML `download` em uma tab `<a>` que link a imagem. Então vc coloca essa tag `<a href="link da imagem"`> envolvendo a tag `<img>` e pronto. ***A ressalva é que para este atributo funcionar a URL de origem e destino devem estar na mesma origem.***

**OBS:** ***Não funciona localmente***, só funciona se estiver no Servidor, mesmo que seja no Xamp ou Wamp.

Vc pode mer mais aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes

```html
<a href="caminho da imagem" download>
  <img src="caminho da imagem" alt="">
</a>
```

Comment: Eu testei esse modo, mas quando clico pra baixar, ele abre a página com a imagem

Comment: Outros arquivos ele baixa

Comment: @PedroHenrique aqui funcionou... não sei se isso pode ser alguma config de segurança do browser que vc usa, ou do server.... Mas aqui deu certo, e olha que eu fiz na mão pelo DevTools, nem precisei subir nada no FTP... Vc tem o link do site? **É provável que localmente isso não funcione, vc precisa colocar o arquivo no serve e testar pra ver!**

Comment: Eu to usando vue js webpack como frontend, e laravel como backend, vou testar agora o download no mesmo dominio

Comment: Testei com um aquivo, e é como você tinha mencionado, funciona apenas se estiver no mesmo dominio

Comment: @PedroHenrique legal que deu certo! Talvez com JS tb de certo. As vezes aparece alguma resposta mais simples.